# Change the UI image using script in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the **UI image** in random order. I have a gameobject in **UI(canvas)** containing **Image component** and it has *null image* initially. I have a script attached to it(gameobject) to change the image on run time.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class changeImg : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite sprite1;
public Sprite sprite2;
public Sprite sprite3;

void Start()
  {
   ChangeImg();
  }
void ChangeImg()
   {
      int rand=Random.Range(0,3);
      if(rand==0)
        {
         gameObject.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sprite1;
        //gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image> ().sprite = sprite1;
         }
       else if(rand==1)
        {
         gameObject.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sprite2;
       // gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image> ().sprite = sprite2;
         }
       else if(rand==2)
        {
         gameObject.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sprite3;
       //gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image> ().sprite = sprite3;
         }
   }
}
```

I have assigned the public field (sprite1,sprite2,sprite3) in inspector. And I tried the both option as I had commented in code. I did not get an error but also the image did not get change as I want. **During runtime of a program, GameObject(to which the script is attached) has null image source as it was initially.**

Comment: your code works for me. Please provide a screenshot of the inspector of the object so I can get a clear understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Yes it works fine with me as well. Are you sure you've assigned those three sprites a value in the inspector?

Comment: Or you sure the script is attached? If there were no Image on that object, you'd get a null reference exception, if no error, maybe no code is run. Put a debug to check.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to see the values of your sprite fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `overrideSprite` field instead of `sprite` - [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-overrideSprite.html)

Unfortunately, unity ui is full of such pitfalls and it's api is totally counter-intuitive, so you have to be careful and check the docs regularly

Comment: his code works as is. His problem is in another place I think.

Comment: huh, I just think I remember having the same problem, and `overrideSprite` did it. Let's see what op says

Comment: @Dunno Thanks , I got my image change using overrideSprite. The code mentioned above is slightly change as shown below:      **gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image> ().overrideSprite = sprite1;** And I  change other two sprites similarly. And it works fine.

Comment: ok now I want to know why  OP's code works for me but not him. What could be different ?

Comment: @UriPopov @ero maybe "null image" is actually a sprite, not just the `null` value?

Comment: Anyway, like I said, unity ui is just weird and forces you to do hacks you don't really understand. Unity forum is full of answers (even made by the devs!) that just tell you to use a different field because this one doesn't work like you think it works.

Comment: @Dunno it works for me even with another sprite already in place. I've always simply used Image.sprite to change a UI sprite during runtime.

Comment: This worked for me thank you so much! Keep in mind, you have to use override after you have already defined rend = GetComponent<Image>(); in your Start function.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just use Image if you are in Unity 2017.3 (not sure if this works for older versions). For example:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
-----
public Image ObjectwithImage;
public Sprite spriteToChangeItTo;

void Start () {
        ObjectwithImage.sprite = spriteToChangeItTo;
    }
```

Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the position of the Gameobject? Also the color of the image?

Answer (score 0):

To change the `Image` from a `Button`, don't use `GetComponent<Image> ()` as you can potentially get another `Image` component that does not belong to the button. It can also return `null` if the object is disabled.

Use the `Button.image.sprite` or `Button.image.overrideSprite` variable instead.

```
public Button pb;
public Sprite newSprite;

void Start()
{
    pb.image.sprite = newSprite; 
}
```

Or

```
pb.image.overrideSprite = newSprite;
```

It really **doesn't** matter which one is used. Any of these two should work.