# Add an Icon next to a text inside a button Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to add an icon and a text inside a button in Unity 5.6 dynamically by the c# script  like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TewT6.png)

My script:

```
GameObject button = Instantiate (BtnTemplate)as GameObject;
button.GetComponent<ButtonListButton().SetText("Text");
```

//inButtonListButton script:

```
 public void SetText(string strText){
        tmpStr = strText;
        BtnTxt.text = strText;
```

But i dont know how can i do it via script. i instantiate the button dynamically and  i want to add icons and texts to a button dynamically too.

Thanks.
Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code? Does it work or not?

Comment: It's work correctly but i want to add an icon to button too,

Comment: Button already has icon. You want to change that icon?

Comment: it dont has icon, l have a list of buttons with just a text

Comment: the list of buttons in my app: http://hpics.li/79250fc

Comment: A button const of a UI Image and a Text component. Are you sure you are using a button? It would be good to post a screenshot of the "Button's" Hierarchy tab. This will show us what exactly you are using.

Comment: Screenshot of Hierarchy tab: http://hpics.li/24654cd

Comment: Screenshot of inspector when i click on a button :http://hpics.li/57a34dd

Comment: It is a button and it has an image component. I have posted a clear way to change this on another question since the accepted answer is not clear. see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368885/3785314).

Comment: Thanks, i try it :)

Comment: You  are welcome.

Comment: @Programmer I'm pretty sure that what he wants to do is add another image inside the button so it has the background image plus an icon next to a text - if that's the case then it's not really a duplicate, at least not of that question.

Comment: @Fiffe, yes exactly,  i want add an icon next to a text to a button :)

Comment: @Programmer, i have achieved this result, but it's not the result which i want:(  http://hpics.li/98711bb

Comment: @Fiffe This question was marked as a duplicate by **another** user. I made a comment to verify and OP replied to my second comment so that made me believe it is a duplicate like another person said. I then marked it as a duplicate. OP doesn't know how to clearly explain  a problem.

Comment: @mkab Why not show what that should instead look like?

Comment: @Programmer yes, that's true

Comment: Maybe, I didn't explain my question correctly, I'm sorry. its not matter that my question is duplicated or not.